# It is possible in chrome to run a code as soon as a variable is detected in window?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am working on an application that makes a lots of debugging calls on start. It also has a global object where I can disable those calls in run time. It is possible to instruct Chrome to automatically look and wait until  that variable is available an then run a function inside? Something like:

```
if(globalVariable) {
   globalVariable.someFunction();
} else {
   // keepWaiting
}
```

Comment: Use setInterval/clearInterval.

Comment: @wOxxOm I can write a function that looks for it. But I do not know how to make it run automatically in each page load.

Comment: Devtools can't do that. You'll need an extension like Tampermonkey.